# Kotlin - data class generics that can accept one of the 2 types for one of the paramaters

Tags: kotlin, generics

I would like to achieve something where I could call a data class with either an `Int` or `BigDecimal` type. So for example:

```
data class Money(val amount: Int, val currencyCode: CurrencyCode) {

  fun toSmallestUnit(): Int = when (this.currencyCode) {
    CurrencyCode.USD -> this.amount * 100
    CurrencyCode.EUR -> this.amount * 100
  }
}
```

Here I would like to be able to send both `Int` and `BigDecimal` as an amount to data class `Money`, and then have different `toSmallestUnit` function for each type. How can I achieve this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you use this class in code, the compiler has to know which type `amount` is for you to be able to do anything with it. If we were working with your own classes, you could define an interface that they both implement, but this is not possible with Int/BigDecimal.

So, I propose you design your class to simply use BigDecimal as the type of `amount`, and provide constructors and properties to allow it to convert from Int.

This is just an example. I'm not sure how it makes sense to convert a currency in BigDecimal to an integer.

```
data class Money(val amount: BigDecimal, val currencyCode: CurrencyCode) {
    
    constructor(amount: Int, currencyCode: CurrencyCode): this(amount.toBigDecimal(), currencyCode)
    
    val intAmount: Int get() = amount.toInt()

    fun toSmallestUnit(): Int = when (this.currencyCode) {
        CurrencyCode.USD -> intAmount * 100
        CurrencyCode.EUR -> intAmount * 100
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is like this

```
data class Money<T>(val amount: T, val currencyCode: CurrencyCode) {
    fun toSmallestUnit(): T = when(amount) {
        is Int -> {
            when (this.currencyCode) {
                CurrencyCode.USD -> (this.amount * 100) as T
                CurrencyCode.EUR -> (this.amount * 100) as T
            }
        }
        is BigInteger -> {
            when (this.currencyCode) {
                CurrencyCode.USD -> this.amount.multiply(BigInteger("100")) as T
                CurrencyCode.EUR -> this.amount.multiply(BigInteger("100")) as T
            }
        }
        else -> {
            amount
        }
    }
}
```

`toSmallestUnit` will return the right result type depending on the type. But as you can see it then does allow to create `Money` of any type

Comment: is there a way to restrict it to only 2 possible types?

Comment: Not that I know of. But maybe others know a way. Although I think for your use case my solution might be good enough. If you by accident create a `Money` object that's not of `Int` or `BigInteger` the compiler would already be able to detect and warn if you use `toSmallestUnit` at a place where `Int` or `BigInteger` is expected. But maybe someone else knows a better way :)

Comment: A cleanish way to restrict the types with this solution would be to make the constructor of the data class private and add a factory method (taking amount: Any and currencyCode as params) in the companion object to instantiate, which blocks all types except Int or BigInteger.

Comment: @somethingsomething could you write an example of that?

Comment: @IvoBeckers is there a way of doing this without having the need to change all Money invocations to Money<T> in the code?

Comment: @Leff you don't need to do that at all. If you defined your Money data class like my solution you just make new Money objects using `Money(100, CurrencyCode.EUR)` for example. The compiler is smart enough to get the type from that

Comment: My compiler is throwing an error, weird, will try to build it again to see if it still gives the same error

Comment: I still get One type argument expected for class Money<T> error

Comment: @IvoBeckers sorry it is not giving errors when invoking it, only when I define Money as a type for paramaters and return type of functions. Is there a way of avoiding of having to change all of this?

Comment: hmm yeah, there it would still be necessary. not sure what to do about that. sorry

Comment: @IvoBeckers is it safe to put then everywhere just a star projection Money<*>?

Comment: It's always safe to use star projection, but then you won't be able to access the `amount` property.

Comment: @Tenfour04 so how should I do it then?

Comment: I don't think you can handle it with two types at once and still have it be fully featured. The compiler always has to know which type its dealing with to be able to work with the `amount`. I'll post my suggested alternative.